# Syntax Error at or near "CONSTRAINT" PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints, create-table

I'm trying to create a new table and keep getting a `syntax error at or near "CONSTRAINT"` in the statement below.  I've already made sure I have a `,` after the last column I declare, which is `Tags` right above the CONSTRAINT line.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  All the online examples of declaring constraints seem to involve CREATE TABLE statements, not CREATE TABLE AS statements.  Does that matter?  Thanks for your help!

By the way, the constraint line below was copied/pasted from a table that I created already, which used a CREATE TABLE statement, not a CREATE TABLE AS statement, which is why I ask if constraints don't work with CREATE TABLE AS statements.

```
CREATE TABLE "2017Projects" AS
SELECT
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_NUMBER", 
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_STATUS",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_TEMPLATE_FLAG",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_START_DATE",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_COMPLETION_DATE",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_COMPANY",
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_LOCATION_NUMBER",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_PARENT_TASK_NUMBER",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_PARENT_TASK_DESCRIPTION",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_NUMBER",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_DESCRIPTION",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_START_DATE",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_COMPLETION_DATE",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_EBS_ACCOUNT",
    "STAGING_TASKS"."_FUSION_ACCOUNT",
    CASE
        WHEN left("STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_NUMBER",2) = 'C0' THEN 
            '('||"STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_NUMBER"||') '||"STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
        ELSE
            "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
    END AS "Project",
    '('||"STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_NUMBER"||') '||"STAGING_TASKS"."_TASK_DESCRIPTION" AS "Task",
    NULL AS "Investment_Priority",
    NULL AS "Class",
    NULL AS "Tags",

    --ERROR ON NEXT LINE HERE!!!
    CONSTRAINT "2017Projects_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("_PROJECT_NUMBER", "_TASK_NUMBER")
FROM
    "STAGING_PROJECTS";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the constraint using a second statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "2017Projects" AS
SELECT
    "STAGING_PROJECTS"."_PROJECT_NUMBER", 
    ...,
    NULL AS "Tags"
FROM
    "STAGING_PROJECTS";

ALTER TABLE "2017Projects" ADD CONSTRAINT "2017Projects_pk"
    PRIMARY KEY ("_PROJECT_NUMBER", "_TASK_NUMBER")
```

The `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements should be run in a single transaction.

Please have a look through [this great Stack DBA article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126495/create-as-select-with-constraint), with @a_horse_with_no_name as a contributor.

Comment: For reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtableas.html. There is no `constraint` section in `create table as select` grammar.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Sorry, totally missed that for some reason.  I searched for `CREATE TABLE AS` and for some reason only saw the `CREATE TABLE` documentation which shows a `constraint` section.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I was thinking I could do that but was hoping that there was a way to do it in the `CREATE TABLE AS` statement.  Thanks for your help!